# "Advanced Copy" greyed out in DBeaver menu when trying to copy SQL table output as TXT

Tags: sql, copy, dbeaver

I often copy some sample rows and the frame in DBeaver as text for a quick markdown chat note.

Now the "advanced copy" is greyed out.

[image]

How can I get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have you tried turning it off and on again?

(IT Crowd)

Restart DBeaver. The menu will be back.